# netbean 17 can't create c++ project

Tags: c++, netbeans

I just install netbean 17. When start create new project. It didn't see any library, except lightweight c++. I select it for try, then click next. Next step is not new project. I can't go forward.

Do I miss some netbean c++ plugin? I try to search any of them on Apache Netbean, but I didn't found addition. How can I do?

Comment: Good question. NetBeans abandoned their previous approach of using C++plugins. That had worked really well, but they are no longer compatible with the JDK releases that NetBeans supports. Instead you must now specify a **CCLS Location** or **clangd Location** using **Tools > Options > C/C++**, but there is no supporting documentation at all. See the long NetBeans email thread titled [_"C/C++ is NetBeans really worth using?"_](https://www.mail-archive.com/users@netbeans.apache.org/msg06352.html) asking _"Where can I get more documentation on how to use NetBeans >> >> with C/C++"_. Nobody knows!